# Correlation matrix with same pairwise correlation coefficient

Tags: matrices, statistics, finance, economics

**Question**

Correlation matrix. Consider  random variables with the same pairwise correlation
coefficient $\rho_n$. Find the highest possible value of $\rho_n$ for

a) n=3

b) n=4

c) general, n $\geq$ 2

HINT: Correlation matrix must be positive semi-definite.

**My Workings**

This is what I infer from "same pairwise coefficients":

$$
    \begin{pmatrix}
    1 & \rho_n & \rho_n \\
    \rho_n & 1 & \rho_n \\
    \rho_n & \rho_n & 1 \\
    \end{pmatrix}
$$

Because a correlation matrix is positive semi-definite, all principal minors have to be positive

For n=3, the principal minors calculations yield

$∣H_1∣$=1

$∣H_2∣$=1-$\rho_n^2$ $\geq 0$ $\Rightarrow $ $\rho_n$ $\leq 1$

$∣H_3∣=\rho_n^2$ - $\rho_n$ $\geq 0$ $\Rightarrow $ $\rho_n$ $\geq 1$

$∣H_4∣=(1^3$+2$\rho_n^3$)-(3$\rho_n^2$)$\geq 0$ $ . $ *I solved for the roots and found 1*

Conclusion: For n=3, max $\rho_n$=1

*I did the same method for n=4 and found max $\rho_n$=1 again*

**My Problem**

Result looks too simple and false. Method is tedious

I have no idea how to do the general case. (by induction ?)

Thank you for your help

$\\$

**INDUCTION ATTEMPT**

$H_0$: n=2

$$
    \begin{pmatrix}
    1 & \rho_2 \\
    \rho_2 & 1 \\
    \end{pmatrix}
$$

1-$\rho_2^2 \geq 0 $ $\Rightarrow - \frac{1}{2-1} \leq \rho_2 \leq 1$

$H_n$: Pn: Suppose that for a nxn correlation matrix $ A_n$ with same pairwise coefficients $ \rho_n$, $ -\frac{1}{n-1} \leq \rho_n \leq 1 $ holds

$H_{n+1}$:

$ -\frac{1}{n-1} \leq \rho_n \leq 1 $

$ \Leftarrow \Rightarrow$ $- \frac{1}{(n+1)-1} \leq \rho_{n+1} \leq 1 $

$ \Leftarrow \Rightarrow$ $- \frac{1}{n} \leq \rho_{n+1} \leq 1 $

And because for all n>1, $- \frac{1}{n} \geq -\frac{1}{n-1}$

$ -\frac{1}{n-1} \leq \rho_{n+1} \leq 1 $

Comment: What do you get if all the random variables are _equal_ to each other, with probability 1?

Comment: I don’t understand why you are asking me this but I’m pretty sure you’d get 1

Answer (score 4):

A symmetric matrix is positive semidefinite if and only if all eigenvalues are nonnegative.

This type of correlation matrix has eigenvalues $\lambda_1 =1 +(n-1) \rho_n$ of multiplicity $1$ and $\lambda_2 =1 - \rho_n$ of multiplicity $n-1$.  By inspection it is easy to see that the vector $e_1 + e_2 + \ldots + e_n = (1,1,\ldots,1)^T$ is an eigenvector corresponding to $\lambda_1$.  Since the matrix is real symmetric the remaining eigenvectors are orthogonal.  Again by inspection, we see that $e_1-e_2, e_1 - e_3, \ldots e_1 - e_n$ are the remaining eigenvectors all corresponding to $\lambda_2$.

The conditions for the matrix to be positive semidefinite are

$$1 - \rho_n \geqslant 0, \,\, 1 +(n-1)\rho_n  \geqslant 0,$$

which implies for all $n \geqslant 2$,

$$-\frac{1}{n-1} \leqslant \rho_n \leqslant 1$$

**Using Principal Minors**

Principal minors are determinants of submatrices obtained by deleteing rows and columns with the same indexes.

For $n=3$:

The three first-order principal minors are obtained by deleting (1) the first and second rows and columns,  (2) the first and third rows and columns, and (3) the second and third rows and columns.  All have value $1$.

The three second-order principal minors are obtained by deleting (1) the first row and column,  (2) the second row and column, and (3) the third row and column.  All have value

$$\begin{vmatrix}
1 & \rho_3\\
\rho_3 & 1
\end{vmatrix} = 1 - \rho_3^2$$

The third-order principal minor is the full determinant

$$D_3 = \begin{vmatrix}
1 & \rho_3 & \rho_3\\
\rho_3 & 1 & \rho_3 \\ \rho_3 &  \rho_3 &1
\end{vmatrix} = 1 - 3\rho_3^2 + 3 \rho_3^3 = (1 +2 \rho_3)(1- \rho_3)^2$$

To ensure that all principal minors are nonnegative we must have

$$1 - \rho_3^2 \geqslant 0 \implies \rho_3 \leqslant 1, \\ (1 +2 \rho_3)(1- \rho_3)^2 \implies \rho_3 \geqslant - 1/2,$$

and the largest  possible value is $\rho_3 = 1$ if the matrix is positive semi-definite.

For n = 4:

Because all off-diagonal entries are identical the principal minors of first-, second- and third-order are identical (replacing $\rho_3$ with $\rho_4$) to those obtained for $n =3$, imposing the requirement $-1/2 \leqslant \rho_4 \leqslant 1$.

The fourth-order principal minor is the determinant

$$D_4 = \begin{vmatrix}
1 & \rho_4 & \rho_4 &\rho_4\\
\rho_4 & 1 & \rho_4 & \rho_4\\ \rho_4 &  \rho_4 &1 &\rho_4 \\ \rho_4 &  \rho_4 &\rho_4 &1 
\end{vmatrix} =  \begin{vmatrix}
1 - \rho_4 & \rho_4 - 1 & 0 & 0\\
\rho_4 & 1 & \rho_4 & \rho_4\\ \rho_4 &  \rho_4 &1 &\rho_4 \\ \rho_4 &  \rho_4 &\rho_4 &1 
\end{vmatrix} $$

where the RHS is obtained by subtracting the second row from the first row in the LHS.

Expanding we get

$$D_4 = (1 - \rho_4) \begin{vmatrix}
1 & \rho_4 & \rho_4\\  \rho_4 &1 &\rho_4 \\   \rho_4 &\rho_4 &1 
\end{vmatrix}- (\rho_4 -1) \begin{vmatrix}
\rho_4 & \rho_4 & \rho_4\\  \rho_4 &1 &\rho_4 \\   \rho_4 &\rho_4 &1 
\end{vmatrix}$$

Using the result for $D_3$ for the first determinant on the RHS and subtracting the third column from the first column in the second determinant we get

$$D_4 = (1-\rho_4)(1 + 2\rho_4)(1- \rho_4)^2 - (\rho_4-1)(\rho_4 - 1)\rho_4(\rho_4- 1) \\ = (1 + 3\rho_4)(1- \rho_4)^3$$

Given that we must have $\rho_4 \leqslant 1$, the only new constraint obtained by imposing $D_4 \geqslant 0$ is $\rho_4 \geqslant -1/3$.

For $n >4$:

Proceeding inductively we find the same conditions obtained for $n -1$ and the additional condition obtained by examining the $n$th-order principal minor. Using the same manipulations as above this can be expanded in two terms involving lower-order determinants leading to

$$D_n = (1 + (n-1) \rho_n) (1 - \rho_n)^{n-1}$$

For all $n$ the largest possible value ensuring that the matrix is positive semi-definite is $\rho_n = 1$.

Comment: i have not learned about all of that. Surely there is a simpler way?

Comment: @WesleyCrusher:  What is your understanding of what it means for a real, symmetric matrix to be positive semidefinite? There are a variety of equivalent conditions like $x^TAx \geqslant 0$ for all non-zero vectors $x$.  They all tie back to the condition that all eigenvalues are nonnegative.  Are you familiar with eigenvalues?  What do you mean by simpler way -- using principal minors?

Comment: Also principal minors are obtained by deleting rows and columns with the same indices. For $n=2$ the three first order PMs are all $1$ and the three second order PMs are all $1 = \rho^2$.  You did get the correct result thought that $\rho_3$ can be no bigger than $1$.

Comment: Correction :  For $n=3$ the second order PMs are all $1-\rho^2$.

Comment: yes, principal minors are what i meant. I did it exactly like above for n=3 and n=4 but i am struggling for the general case n>2. I did it by induction and found the right result but it looks just wrong. Im gonna include the induction in my answer

Comment: i find the induction good enough to prove the condition $ \rho_n$ > -1/n-1 but not for $ \rho_n$ < 1. And since i am trying to find the upper bound...